# Calling oci_free_statement Before oci_commit

Tags: php, oci8

I found some instability issues especially missing inserted records and I suspect that calling oci_free_statement before oci_commit is causing issue. I tried to simulate this several times, but I not able to replicate in my test environment.

```
    oci_execute($mySql, OCI_DEFAULT);
    oci_free_statement($mySql);
    oci_commit($myCon);
```

Is calling oci_free_statement before oci_commit can cause such issue?

Comment: Thats sounds logical, but what is your question

Comment: I just added my question.

Comment: It should not cause a problem.